# Is it possible to select by range on leftmost multiple-index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, range, myisam, multiple-columns

I have an index `m_idx` on `(k1,k2,k3)`
If I do
`SELECT c1,c2,c3... FROM tb FORCE INDEX (m_idx) WHERE k1=500 AND k2 IN(...) AND k2>2000 ORDER BY k1 LIMIT 1000;`
OR
`SELECT c1,c2,c3... FROM tb FORCE INDEX (m_idx) WHERE k1 IN (500,1000,1500 ...) AND k2 IN(...) AND k2>2000 ORDER BY k1 LIMIT 1000;`
Handler_read_next = 999

BUT if I try to use a range on k1:
`SELECT c1,c2,c3... FROM tb FORCE INDEX (m_idx) WHERE k1>=500 AND k2 IN(...) AND k2>2000 ORDER BY k1 LIMIT 1000;`
Handler_read_next = 58035
In all cases EXPLAIN  says that the key used is `m_idx`
But I think that in the third case `m_idx` it's not used (I also have an index only on k1).
Otherwise I don't understand why it'is reading more than 1000 rows.
I was expecting to scan `m_idx` index, and `ONLY the first 1000` rows that meet the conditions to be read from table.
But in fact I think that for the third case it scans the index and those rows who meet k1 condition are read from the tb and k2 and k3 conditions are checked after the rows are read from tb.
I use: MySql with MyISAM, WINDOWS 7 64, the tb has 1 mil rows;
So my questions are:
Is it possible to select by range on leftmost multiple-index?
OR
I'm doing something else wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No it is not.
2. No, you're doing everything right

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/range-optimization.html ("7.3.1.3.2. The Range Access Method for Multiple-Part Indexes" part)

So you cannot help optimizer to perform this query faster.

And avoid using `FORCE INDEX`, since optimizer knows better what index to use.

Also:

```
k1>=500 AND k2 IN(...) AND k2>2000
```

Depending of which part returns fewer records, either `k1>=500` or `k2 IN(...) AND k2>2000` (I'm not sure why do you need `> 2000` here, due to you can compare it manually, before add to `IN()`), you could also try to create index `k2` (if `k2` part returns less amount of records).

Comment: I've already read that chapter and I didn't find no were to say explicit  that it's not  possible. Plus it is even more confusing since it says: `For a BTREE index, an interval might be usable for conditions combined with AND, where **each condition** compares a key part with a constant value using =, <=>, IS NULL, >, <, >=, <=, !=, <>, BETWEEN, or LIKE`  It even says: **where each condition**!!!

Comment: @silversky: yes, **might be**, but not in your case (and not in every case). It is technically possible, yes, but not for such kind of queries. "An interval can be used as long as it is possible to determine a single key tuple containing all rows that match the condition" -- this is key phrase. Also look at the sample right after this phrase - it is completely like yours.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think that I'm wrong if I say that this documentations are really bad sometimes. In the first paragraph of the chapter it says: `A range condition on a multiple-part index restricts index rows to lie within one or several key tuple intervals.` And later it says (like you pointed out): `to determine a single key tuple`

Comment: @zerkms Since, when I use k1 IN (...) it's working I was hopping maybe I do something wrong. But probably you're wright. Although I don't see any reason why it's not implemented this option also.

Comment: @silversky: try to implement the search in B-Tree (composed from 2 values) manually from scratch in any programming language. After that  - implement the search like `k1>A and k2>B` ;-) I agree, mysql developers are much experienced than you and me, but this solution can be a bit tricky.

Comment: @zerkms If I add this condion: `AND ROUND( 4550 * acos( 0.7767 *k4 * cos( k6 - (-1.67075)) +0.6298 * k5 ) ) <= @d`. WHY it's not working (I mean, why is not using only the index)? k4,k5,k6 are part of `m_idx` also (k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6).  Is it because  k4,k5,k6 are used on the some condition?

Comment: @silversky: it is because `k4` is not used as the only part of condition, but as the part of some expression. Any expression (like: `field + 1` or `FUNCTION(field)`) will prevent mysql of optimizing it by index.